# For $a>0$, prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos ax\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$ by justifying term by term integration.

Tags: real-analysis

> For $a>0$, prove $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos ax\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$ by justifying term by term integration.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos ax\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{(ax)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\,dx
$$
I wonder how to justify that the integral sign and the summation sign can be interchanged? I want to use Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I can't find a Dominated function. I only need to know how to do this way but no other methods. This is an exercise in Folland's Real Analysis, he hints that it can be proved this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since for any $n\in \mathbb N$,$$\left|e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{(ax)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right|\leq e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(a|x|)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\leq e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(a|x|)^{k}}{k!}=e^{-x^2+a|x|},$$
and $$\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2+a|x|}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2+ax}\,dx<\infty,$$
we can use DCT to change the order of integration and summation.

Comment: Thanks. What about for $a>1$, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}(e^x-1)^{-1}\,dx=\Gamma(a)\zeta(a)$, where $\displaystyle\zeta(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a}$?

Comment: @TaoX In this case, you can consider using monotone convergence since all terms in the series all non-negative, or consider Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: @FengShao How do you know that $$e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(a|x|)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\leq e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(a|x|)^{k}}{k!}?$$ I don't get it.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Fix $x$, denote $f(k)=e^{-x^2}\frac{(a|x|)^{k}}{k!}$, then $f(k)>0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. So we have $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k)\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k+1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n),$$this is exactly what I claimed.